# Difference between text file encoding in Android

Tags: unicode

What is the difference between different text file encoding for my Android project, such as:

- UTF-8
- UTF-16BE
- UTF-16LE
- UTF-16
- ISO-8859-1
- US-ASCII

For example, for displaying Korean, I know I should use UTF-8. But when I should use the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Character_encoding and their difference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding.

Usually UTF-8 works fine for cross platform and multiple language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

But Korean version of Windows also use **Unified Hangul Code**

> Unified Hangul Code (UHC) extends Wansung Code by adding the missing
>   8,822 Hangul characters, and is designed for smooth migration to
>   Unicode Version 2.0. All Wansung code points map directly to the same
>   UHC code points (but not vice versa). UHC also provides round trip
>   mapping with Unicode Version 2.0. UHC is used in Korean versions of
>   Windows 95 and Windows NT.

There is this command `iconv` under Linux (and also libiconv for c programming language), for encoding translation.

```
iconv -l
```

to list all encoding that `iconv` supports.

Comment: Then when should I use any of these: UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-16, ISO-8859-1, US-ASCII?